# How to construct JSON with multiple sub-keys with parson library

Tags: c, json

I am using the library parson to construct JSON messages. I did not figure it out how to make sub-key without using the dotfonction. The JSON, I would like to make is :

```
"received_data": {
    "X-YY": {
        "pm10": 1,
        "pm25": 2,
        "pm100": 3
    },
    "X-ZZ": {
        "pm10": 1,
        ...
    }
}
```

From now I only found how to make the JSON Array to get "pm10,pm25,pm100" values by using this code :

```
//creating a sub Json_Array
JSON_Value *branch = json_value_init_array();
JSON_Array *leaves = json_value_get_array(branch);

//creating measurement Json
JSON_Value *leaf_value = json_value_init_object();
JSON_Object *leaf_object = json_value_get_object(leaf_value);
json_object_set_string(leaf_object,"PM10:",val);
json_object_set_string(leaf_object,"PM25:",val1);
json_object_set_string(leaf_object,"PM100:",val2);
json_array_append_value(leaves,leaf_value);
```

I don't really understand how to link the keys between them using the parson library ? Can someone help me figure it out ?